# Differences between df, df -h, and df -l

Tags: disk-usage

### Question

What are the differences between the *following* commands?

```
df

df -h

df -l
```

### Feedback

Information is *greatly* appreciated. **Thank you.**

Comment: As suggested [in the answer below](http://askubuntu.com/a/425796/248158), please use `man` before asking here. It may save your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of, `df` reports file system disk space usage. That is, it displays the total size, the used and available space for each of your mounted partitions.

```
df
```

is the default behavior, without arguments. Sizes are given in 1K-blocks (that is, 1024 bytes). Local filesystems (i.e., on hard drives on the present machine) as well as remote filesystems (e.g., mounted via NFS on a network) are listed.

```
df -h
```

tells `df` to display sizes in Gigabyte, Megabyte, or Kilobyte as appropriate, akin to the way a human would describe sizes. Actually, the `h` stands for "human-readable".

```
df -l
```

tells `df` to display only local filesystems, but no remote ones.

Answer (score 2):

`df` - disk space shown in 1K blocks

`df -h` - disk space shown in human readable form (KB, MB, GB)

`df -l` - limit listing to local file systems

This info can be found in man pages. Try `man df`.

Answer (score 1):

Type in terminal for each command you want to know :

```
man <the command>
```

it will list its usage and options .

in your example type `man df`